# Md-file-input doesn't append in formData in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, upload, append, multipartform-data

In an Anggular web app I have a form. I want to update a file, so I used lf-ng-md-file-input. This is the easy html:

```
<lf-ng-md-file-input lf-files='files' multiple> </lf-ng-md-file-input>
```

In my Controller, I did this:

```
let formData = new FormData();
angular.forEach(this.$scope.files,function(obj){
   formData.append('files[]', obj.lfFile);
});
```

Debugging it, I see that obj.lfFile exists:

```
lastModified:1473694273813
lastModifiedDate:Mon Sep 12 2016 17:31:13 GMT+0200 (ora legale Europa occidentale)
name:"test.jpg"
size:39790
type:"image/jpeg"
webkitRelativePath:""
```

The problem is that it doesn't append the file in my formData. It is still empty after the loop. Why?

Comment: Can you modify [this DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/S642uACPAaVFMrGYmRwD?p=preview) to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a directive for this once, maybe it'll help you out:

DIRECTIVE:

```
angular.module('content')
    .directive('parFiles', files);

/* @ngInject */
function files($parse, $timeout) {

    var directive = {
        link: link,
        restrict: 'A'
    };

    return directive;

    function link(scope, element, attr) {
        var fn = $parse(attr['pirFiles']);

        element.bind('change', function (evt) {
            var files = [], fileList, i;
            fileList = evt.target.files;
            if (fileList != null) {
                for (i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
                    files.push(fileList.item(i));
                }
            }
            $timeout(function () {
                fn(scope, {
                    $files: files,
                    $event: evt
                });
            });
        });
    }
}
```

VIEW:

```
 <input type="file"
        class="input-list__item"
        ng-disabled="dr.isFileUploaded"
        par-files="dr.addFiles($files)"
        required />
```

CONTROLLER:

```
function addFiles(files) {
    vm.files = files;
}
```

Comment: In the directive, after the if(fileList != null) {...} I've written: 
            let formData = new FormData();

            formData.append("files", files[0]);

but it cannot append the file yet. Why?

Comment: Are you sure that files actually has data??

Comment: The debug of chrome console shows me that files[0] is this: lastModified
:
1473694273813
lastModifiedDate
:
Mon Sep 12 2016 17:31:13 GMT+0200 (ora legale Europa occidentale)
name
:
"test.jpg"
size
:
39790
type
:
"image/jpeg"
webkitRelativePath
:
""

Comment: Then; shouldn't it just be `formData.append('file', obj);` ?

Comment: No, after the append, this is the value of formData: __proto__
:
FormData